# Getting a URL from (to) a "picked" image, iOS

Tags: ios, url, uiimagepickercontroller

With this code below, I can extract metadata from an image (pre-added to my project), and render the info as text. This is exactly what I want to do. The `SYMetadata` is created by pointing to an image via URL. `initWithAbsolutePathURL`. I want to do the same thing with a UIImage or maybe the image that is being loaded to the UIImage. How do I get the URL to the image that the picker selects? Or how do I create an "asset" from this incoming image?

The documentation describes `initWithAsset`. Have not figured out how to use it yet though, or if this is the right way to go for my purpose. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"someImage" withExtension:@"jpg"];
SYMetadata *metadata = [[SYMetadata alloc] initWithAbsolutePathURL:imageURL];
[textView setText:[[metadata allMetadatas] description]];
```

**Note**: I tried adding an NSURL like this `imageURL = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];`, in the "pickerDidFinish" method but the metadata is null after I add this URL to the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the imagePickerController, the delegate method will give you what you need

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    if ([[info allKeys] containsObject:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]){
        // you will get this key if your image comes from a library
        [self setMetaDataFromAssetLibrary:info];
    } else if ([[info allKeys] containsObject:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]){
        // if the image comes from the camera you get the metadata in it's own key
        self.rawMetaData = [self metaDataFromCamera:info];
    }
}
```

From Asset Library - bear in mind that it takes time to complete and has an asynchronous completion block, so you might want to add a completion flag to ensure you don't access the property before it has been updated.

```
- (void) setMetaDataFromAssetLibrary:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:assetURL
             resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
                 self.rawMetaData = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
             }
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog (@"error %@",error);
            }];
}
```

From Camera:

```
    - (NSDictionary*)metaDataFromCamera:(NSDictionary*)info
   {
        NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
       return imageMetadata;
   }
```

Here is how to get metadata from a UIImage

```
  - (NSDictionary*)metaDataFromImage:(UIImage*)image
   {
        NSData *jpegData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
        return [self metaDataFromData:jpegData];
    }
```

But take care - a UIImage can already stripped of much of the metadata from the original.. you will be better off getting the metadata from the NSData that was used to create the UIImage...

```
    - (NSDictionary*)metaDataFromData:(NSData*)data
{
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);
    CFDictionaryRef imageMetaData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
    return (__bridge NSDictionary *)(imageMetaData);
}
```

Comment: When I try to run [self metaDataFromCamera:info]; I get an error, the method is not recognized. (no visible interface for viewController declares selector metaDataFromCamera:info). Do i need to add a library?

Comment: @Mrwolfy sorry, i missed out the method: check my updated reply. It is just a 1-liner: I broke it out to a separate method because I am making a collection of metadata reading and writing methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you've an ALAsset (in my sample _detailItem), you can have metadata in this way:

```
NSDictionary *myMetadata = [[_detailItem defaultRepresentation] metadata];
```

Comment: Please explain how do I get the ALAsset, not understanding the concept yet. Thanks!!

Comment: A good example for using ALAssetsLibrary is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html