# Save image with the correct orientation - Swift & Core Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image, photo-gallery

I'm using **Core Image** in **Swift** for editing photos and I have a problem when I save the photo. I'm not saving it with correct **orientation**.
When I get the picture from the **Photo Library** I'm saving the orientation in a variable as UIImageOrientation but I don't know how to set it back before saving the edited photo to the Photo Library. Any ideas how?

Saving the orientation:

```
var orientation: UIImageOrientation = .Up
orientation = gotImage.imageOrientation
```

Saving the edited photo to the Photo Library:

```
@IBAction func savePhoto(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let originalImageSize = CIImage(image:gotImage)
    filter.setValue(originalImageSize, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    // 1
    let imageToSave = filter.outputImage

    // 2
    let softwareContext = CIContext(options:[kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: true])

    // 3
    let cgimg = softwareContext.createCGImage(imageToSave, fromRect:imageToSave.extent())

    // 4
    let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
    library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(cgimg,
        metadata:imageToSave.properties(),
        completionBlock:nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `metadata` version of `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`, you can use :

```
library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(
                cgimg,
                orientation: orientation,
                completionBlock:nil)
```

then you can pass in the orientation directly.

To satisfy Swift, you may need to typecast it first:

```
var orientation : ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue:           
                                    gotImage.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
```

As per my somewhat inconclusive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28228047/1375695).

(As you have confirmed, this solution does indeed work in Swift - I derived it, untested, from working Objective-C code)

If you are interested in manipulating other information from image metadata, here are a few related answers I provided to other questions...

[Updating UIImage orientation metaData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553866/updating-uiimage-orientation-metadata/14553970#14553970)
[Force UIImagePickerController to take photo in portrait orientation/dimensions iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484816/force-uiimagepickercontroller-to-take-photo-in-portrait-orientation-dimensions-i/14491293#14491293)
[How to get author of image in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106202/how-to-get-author-of-image-in-cocoa/16123218#16123218)
[Getting a URL from (to) a "picked" image, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664654/getting-a-url-from-to-a-picked-image-ios/14664972#14664972)

And a [small test project on github](https://github.com/foundry/UIImageMetadata) that digs out image metadata from various sources (it's objective-C, but the principles are the same).

Comment: `ALAssetsLibrary()`is deprecated in iOS 9, now you have to use `PHPhotoLibrary`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`... The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:) on that method say:

> You must specify the orientation key in the metadata dictionary to preserve the orientation of the image.